# Why does this loop terminate partway through?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, jsbin

I'm trying to write a program to find the smallest common multiple of the provided parameters that can be evenly divided by both, as well as by all sequential numbers in the range between these parameters.

The range will be an array of two numbers that will not necessarily be in numerical order.

For example, for 1 and 3 - find the smallest common multiple of both 1 and 3 that is evenly divisible by all numbers between 1 and 3.

**Why does the loop stop at i = 510,000 (or something close to that) instead of 7,000,000, as I set it?**

I also have a screenshot with the output:

[image]

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  
  var start;
  var finish;
  var something;
  
  if(arr[0] < arr[1]){start = arr[0]; finish = arr[1];}else{
      start = arr[1]; finish = arr[0];
    }
  
  for(var i = finish;i <= 7000000;i++){
    var boolea = true;
    for(var j = start;j <= finish;j++){
      if(i % j !== 0){boolea = false;break;} // 2 % 1
    }
    
    if(boolea)return i;
    
    something = i;
  }
  
  console.log("final i = " + i);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe browser is out of memory.

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: Try https://jsbin.com/blog/protection#loopprotection to check if jsbin is not forcing your code to exit from the loop

Comment: Thank you, @Gonzalo.-. That worked.

Comment: So I just put //noprotect right under the beginning of the for loop, it will iterate until the end, as it should.

Comment: I will post it as an answer then

Comment: @NarcisNeacsu please consider to upvote and/or set the answer as accepted if it has helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this at the beginning of your loop

```
// noprotect
```

it must be that jsbin is forcing your code to exit from the loop. See [source](https://jsbin.com/blog/protection#loopprotection)